# Question about quadratic function vertex form

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, quadratics

I'm taking Precalculus and I'm learning to graph quadratic functions by rewriting the function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ in the form $f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k$. So, I tried to derive a general formula  keeping the coefficients as $a$, $b$ & $c$. After doing all the algebra, I typed it into Wolfram Alpha to check, and the app said it was "not always equal" to $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. The formula I derived is: $$f(x)=a(x+ \frac{2b}{a})^2+(c-\frac{4b^2}{a})$$ I haven't had the opportunity to ask my professor yet, so I figured I'd ask you guys. My question is this: why is this "not always equal" as Wolfram Alpha says?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @K Ferreira: Your final form of $f(x)$ is $ax^2+4bx+c$ instead of $ax^2+bx+c$. Try $\frac{b}{2a}$ in place of $\frac{2b}{a}$ and determine appropriate $(c-?)$ part.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake in your derivation.

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=a\left(x^2+\frac{bx}{a}\right)+c\\
&=a\left[x^2+2(x)\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)+\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right]+c\\
&=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Now I see, thanks. But, I wonder why Wolfram didn't just say it wasn't equal?

Comment: They are equal when $b=0$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now.

Comment: Then, would $h=-(b/2a)$ and $k=c-(b^2/4a)$ ?

Comment: Yes. And this leads to the quadratic formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula